# Laravel testing: model factory doesn't trigger Registered event

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I’ve used Laravel 5.7 for quite some time now, however, I am totally new to TDD.

If a user model is created, a `register` event is getting triggered. But why isn't it fired when I am creating the user model with a factory?

My factory:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'first_name' => $faker->name,
        'sur_name' => $faker->name,
        'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'birthday' => Carbon::now()->subYears(25)->toDateTimeString(),
        'gender' => 'm',
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

and my Test, which fails:

```
public function test()
{

    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    Event::fake();
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    Event::assertDispatched(Registered::class);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Registered event is dispatched by the *controller* when using the auth scaffolding provided by Laravel (specifically, the `register()` method in the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers` trait. Since you're not making a request through the controller, it doesn't dispatch the event.

Comment: Sorry, my Mistake. That was an copy and paste mistake from tinkering around. Even when I am using create, I am still getting "The expected [Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered] event was not dispatched."

Comment: But Even if I set the `Event::fake()` under the `factory()`, I am still getting the error that no event is getting dispatched. And this also applies to other models, I've tested it on multiple models with multiple events...

Comment: I've updated my answer, it seems that we were both looking at the wrong thing

Comment: Oh yeah... Thats it! Man, Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

From the "Event Fake" section of the docs:

> After calling Event::fake(), no event listeners will be executed. So,
>   if your tests use model factories that rely on events, such as
>   creating a UUID during a model's  creating event, you should call
>   Event::fake() after using your factories.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mocking

Comment: Yes, I've read this. So listeners wouldn't be executed. But I am only checking for an event, not for the listener

Comment: @PatrickSchocke the `Registered` event has to be fired in some sort of listener.  Otherwise why would the user being created fire it? It could be in an eloquent listener, but that is still a listener. Like the doc specified, `such as... during a model's creating event`

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, I've switched the terms. But If I put the `Event::fake()` under the `factory()`, it still returns `The expected [Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered] event was not dispatched.`

Answer (score 1):

As the event `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered` is fired by Laravel when we are registering through laravel's default registration.

When you do  : `$user = factory(User::class)->create();`

It just seeds a new record in database, skipping the registration process. To test default registration you can do something like below :

```
<?php 

public function test_if_user_can_register()
{
    $response = $this->post('/register', [
      'name' => 'John Doe',
      'email' => 'johndoe@test.com',
      'password' => 'secret',
      'password_confirmation' => 'secret'
    ]);

    $response->assertRedirect('/');
    Event::assertDispatched(Registered::class);

    unset($user['password']);
    unset($user['password_confirmation']);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', $user);
}
```

Comment: Does not work. "The expected [Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered] event was not dispatched."